# powershell module startup commands

Tags: powershell

When writing powershell modules (in powershell) how do I have commands run when the module is imported?

When the user runs `import-module mymodule` I want the module to run some commands first to do some initial setup. how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a PowerShell `*.psm1`module, you should also specify a *module manifest* (`*.psd1`). Within this manifest, you can spefiy an array of PowerShell scripts (`*.ps1*`) to invoke when the module gets loaded:

```
# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
ScriptsToProcess = @()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do the `ScriptsToProcess` thing as mentioned, but you can also just put the code directly into the `.psm1` file (outside of a function definition). It all gets executed when the module is imported, so there's no need to use a separate file.  (Anything written to standard output while the on-import code is executing is generally discarded.)

Comment: I've tried this, and it did NOT run when importing the module.

Comment: Disregard. The command was running, and setting the variable I required, but I had a frickin typo later on trying to use the variable.

Comment: unfortunately it won't let me remove my downvote :(

Comment: RossPresser you might be able to upvote instead of just undoing the downvote.

Comment: Nope. "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: @RossPresser oh well, win some lose some ‍♂️

Comment: haha! I added a sentence (adding a tiny bit of information to the answer) and then was able to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve that is to create module manifest when you have module ready. You can achieve that with following cmdlet

```
New-ModuleManifest
```

Check for more details:

```
Get-Help New-ModuleManifest
```

The option you're looking for is

```
-ScriptsToProcess <String[]>
    Specifies script (.ps1) files that run in the caller's session state when the module is imported. You can use these scripts to prepare an environment, just as you might use a login script.


    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: Oh you beat jisaak by a hair. This is what I needed. I guess this would be preferable to just using $PSScriptRoot\somescript.ps1 to get scripts related to module.

Comment: @red888 Its fine, you don't have to accept my answer only because I was a second earlier, just accept that one you find the most helpfull.